# Keep QTableView from scrolling to selected item

Tags: qt, scroll, qtableview

I have two QTableViews (one nested within the other) that share one selection model:

```
void MyTableWidget::setSelectionModel( QItemSelectionModel* in_p_selection_model )
{
    QTableView::setSelectionModel( in_p_selection_model );

    m_p_inner_tableview->setSelectionModel( in_p_selection_model );
}
```

The first QTableView should not automatically scroll to the selected item when I make a selection in the second QTableView. As far as I can tell, there is no "auto scroll to selection" flag. So how can I prohibit this behavior?

Comment: Not quite sure it would work but have you tried setting the [autoScroll](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#autoScroll-prop) property to `false`?

Comment: Yep, this only concerns scrolling while dragging.